# Type inference in C# not working?

Tags: c#, vb.net, type-inference

Given the following C# code:

```
var a = new[] {"123", "321", 1}; //no best type found for implicitly typed array
```

And its counterpart in VB.NET:

```
Dim a = {"123", "321", 1} 'no errors
```

It appears that VB.NET is able to correctly infer type of `a` = `Object()`, while C# complains until the above is fixed to:

```
var a = new object[] {"123", "321", 1};
```

Is there a way to auto-infer type in C# for the above scenario?

**EDIT:** Interesting observation after playing with different types in a C# sandbox - type is correctly inferred if all elements have common parent in the inheritance tree, and that parent is *not* an `Object`, or if elements can be cast into a wider type (without loss of precision, for example `Integer -> Double`). So both of these would work:

```
var a = new[] {1, 1.0}; //will infer double[]
var a = new[] {new A(), new B()}; //will infer A[], if B inherits from A
```

I think this behavior is inconsistent in C#, because all types inherit from `Object`, so it's not a much different ancestor than any other type. This is probably a by-design, so no point to argue, but if you know the reason, would be interesting to know why.

Comment: Just curious, would you be better off using a labeled object instead of an untyped array?

Comment: @CookieOfFortune: Sometimes I need to write quick-and-dirty code, mostly for prototyping reasons, often to help other people on SO. Creating an object for this purpose is not feasible.

Comment: Sorry, I meant an anonymous object: var a = new { Str1 = "123", Str2 = "321", AnInteger = 1 };

Comment: @CookieOfFortune: Then you cannot do `DataTable.Rows.Add(array);`, which would be one of the most common use cases.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Implicitly typed arrays in C# require that the type of *one* of the expressions in the array initializer is of the target type. Basically, the compiler tries to find exactly one element type such that all the other types can be converted to it.

You could cast *any* of the elements to `object` of course:

```
var a = new[] { (object) "123", "321", 1};
```

... but then you might as well just use an explicitly typed array initializer:

```
var a = new object[] {"123", "321", 1};
```

Or in cases where you really *are* declaring a variable at the same time:

```
object[] a = {"123", "321", 1};
```

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for a thorough explanation.

Answer (score 2):

No. However, you can make VB behave more like C# by using Option Explicit On, Option Strict On, and Option Infer Off.

[Best Practices: Option Infer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667851/best-practices-option-infer)

Comment: Can I make C# behave more like VB?

Comment: +1 @Josh C: I wouldn't say "you can", but "you have to!"
@Neolisk: use the the new _dynamic_ keyword `dynamic[] k = { "123", "1", 1 };` Now you have a "something" ...

Comment: +1 Option Explicit **must** be on! Option Strict should **almost always** be on. But you might want to leave Option Infer On otherwise you can't use LINQ.

Comment: @igrimpe: `dynamic` is interesting. Not exactly the same as `Dim k() = {...}`, but please post as an answer, so I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

In C# you could use `dynamic`:
`dynamic[] k = { "1", 2, "3" };`

It doesn't mimic VB's behaviour completey, though.
`dynamic[] k = { "1", "2", "3" };`
still gives you an array of object, while in VB you get an array of String.

And of course:

```
dynamic[] k = { "1", "3", "3" };
int i = k[0].I_do_not_exist();
```

compiles without problem, but most likely will fail miserably ;)