# Odd "implicit conversion" compiler warning in simple LINQ query

Tags: vb.net, linq

Why am I getting an `Implicit conversion from 'Object' to 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow'.` compiler warning on `x As DataGridViewRow` in

```
Dim list = From x As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows Where x.Tag Is "my tag"
```

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linq query has an implicit cast error for DataGridViewRow when option strict is enabled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089059/linq-query-has-an-implicit-cast-error-for-datagridviewrow-when-option-strict-is)

Comment: I always find it curious how people down vote questions they view to be too simplistic.  Sorry I'm not that knowledgeable with LINQ.  That's the point of SO, right?

Comment: How do you know your question was downvoted because it was too simplistic?  Perhaps it was downvoted because it was a duplicate of another question.  Unfortunately, the downvoters did not state a reason.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway -- You're right, I don't know.  But I see it a lot with other questions people post.  The poster is obviously inexperienced with the topic they're posting about, and people who are more experienced seem to mistake a simple question ("how could you NOT know such a simple thing??") for one that breaks the actual rules for asking a good question.  Just my thoughts on it.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway -- Also, it's my understanding that closing a question as a duplicate and down-voting it are to separate yet tangentially-related things.  The only reason I can see that it should be down-voted is that it might show a lack of research effort on my part.   But I did research it, and I didn't come up with `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089059/linq-query-has-an-implicit-cast-error-for-datagridviewrow-when-option-strict-is` because I guess I didn't type in the right search terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Rows` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns a [`DataGridViewRowCollection` instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrowcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which only implements `IEnumerable` (yielding `object`s), not `IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow>`.

To fix this, remove the `As DataGridViewRow` implicit conversion and add an explicit `DirectCast(x, DataGridViewRow)` conversion later in your query.

Comment: So are you saying it's not possible to get rid of that warning?  If not, can you add how to your answer?

Comment: @roryap I don't know how to fix it - I would expect `As DataGridViewRow` to be treated as an explicit conversion in the first place. Apparently `option infer` might help but I'm not hot on VB.

Comment: I have `option infer` turned on already, but since, as you pointed out, `DataGridViewRowCollection` is an `IEnumerable` which only knows `Object` values, we're dealing with true `Objects` and not ones that can be inferred.  I found a solution though, if you want to add it to your answer: I changed my code to `Dim list = From x In DataGridView1.Rows Where DirectCast(x, DataGridViewRow).Tag Is "my tag"` (note the addition of `DirectCast`).

Comment: @roryap Have done so, way to answer your own question :)

Comment: Thanks.  I just wanted to make sure your answer reflected that before I accepted it :)